# Amcharts v4 custom SVG

Tags: svg, amcharts

Is there a way to dynamically build an SVG using sprites in amcharts 4?

Example: [screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kqHa.png)

There are 20 different types which are represented by colors.
Each pin can contain a multitude of types.
So an example can be that a pin has 3 types and will consist out of 3 colors.

I have an SVG path which is a circle.
With regular JS and SVG i can create a path for each type and change the stroke color, strokedasharray and strokedashoffset.
This results in the nice circle with 3 colors.

However this seems to be impossible to do with amcharts 4.

For starters, strokedashoffset is not even a supported property for a sprite. Why would you bother supporting strokedasharray and then ignore strokedashoffet?!

The second problem is finding out how to pass data to the sprite.

This is an example of a data object I pass to the mapImageSeries class.

```
[{
amount: 3,
client: undefined,
colorsArr: {0: "#FFB783", 1: "#FD9797", 2: "#77A538"},
dashArray: "500,1000",
dashOffset: 1500,
divided: 500,
global: true,
groupId: "minZoom-1",
hcenter: "middle",
id: "250",
latitude: 50.53398,
legendNr: 8,
longitude: 9.68581,
name: "Fulda",
offsetsArr: {0: 0, 1: 500, 2: 1000},
scale: 0.5,
title: "Fulda",
typeIds: (3) ["4", "18", "21"],
typeMarker: " type-21 type-18 type-4",
vcenter: "bottom",
zoomLevel: 5
}]
```

It seems impossible to pass the colors down to the sprite.

```
var svgPath = 'M291,530C159,530,52,423,52,291S159,52,291,52s239,107,239,239c0,131.5-106.3,238.3-237.7,239'
var mainPin1 = single.createChild(am4core.Sprite)
mainPin1.strokeWidth = 100
mainPin1.fill = am4core.color('#fff')
mainPin1.stroke = am4core.color('#ff0000')
mainPin1.propertyFields.strokeDasharray = 'dashArray'
mainPin1.propertyFields.strokeDashoffset = 'dashOffset'
mainPin1.path = svgPath
mainPin1.scale = 0.04
mainPin1.propertyFields.horizontalCenter = 'hcenter'
mainPin1.propertyFields.verticalCenter = 'vbottom'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you've provided, simulating your custom SVGs is beyond the scope of what can be answered, so I'll try tackling:

1. applying `stroke-dashoffset` despite lack of innate library support. (I see you've added [a feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/895) for it, so why the library doesn't include it, when/if it will, can be left for discussion there.)
2. passing data/colors to the `Sprite`

For both we're going to have to wait until the instances of `Sprite`s are ready along with their data. Presuming your `single` variable is a reference to a `MapImageSeries.mapImages.template`, we can set up [an `"inited"` event](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/) like so:

```js
single.events.once("inited", function(event){
  // ...
});
```

Our data and [data placeholders](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/#Data_placeholders) don't really support nested arrays/objects in general, since your colors are nested within a field, we can find them via:

```js
event.target.dataItem.dataContext.colorsArr
```

You can then set the `fill` and `stroke` on the `Sprite` or `event.target.children.getIndex(0)` manually from there (in my demo below, the index will be `1` because `mainPin1` is not the first/only child created on the `MapImage` template).

As for `stroke-dashoffset`, you can access the actual rendered SVGElement via `sprite.group.node` and just use `setAttribute`.

I forked our [map image demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/EEdBBj) from our [map image data guide](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Image_data) and added all the above to it here:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6a3d87ff3bdee7b85000fe775af9e583

[image: customized MapImage with colors from data and stroke-dashoffset]